# Receiving event on pusher but the value of data is null

Tags: jquery, pusher, laravel-6

I have a problem Pusher (i am receiving the broadcasted event, but the value of data is null after I have passed it correctly).

I'm using Pusher to dispatch events to my application. I send the event from the app to the pusher (along with my data). I'm sending a text message, just a simple string. On the Pusher debug console, I am receiving the event, but the value of my data is null. I have followed many videos on how to configure my laravel environment, but still, the value of my data is null.

I am a beginner in Pusher and Laravel. I am trying to develop an app of real-time chatting using Laravel Pusher and jQuery. I have watched a lot of video tutorials on it and do a lot of search on it, but still, I can not find a solution to my problem.

```
Route::post('/sender', function () {    
    $text = User::find(1);

    return event(new FormSubmitted($text));
});
```

**Event class**

```php
class FormSubmitted implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $text;

    public function __construct($text)
    {
        $this->$text = $text;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'form-submitted';
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Provide the info of your event class.

Comment: Show us your code. You are sending null value

Comment: i have provide the event class code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code in your constructor.

Instead :

```
$this->$text = $text;  // problem
```

use

```
$this->text = $text;
```